# Read connection string from web.config

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, web-config, connection-string

How can I read a connection string from a `web.config` file into a public class contained within a class library?

I've tried:

```
WebConfigurationManager

ConfigurationManager
```

But these classes are not recognized within my class library.

Answer (score 188, accepted):

Add `System.Configuration` as a reference.

For some bizarre reason it's not included by default.

Answer (score 544):

You need to add a reference to `System.Configuration` and then use:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
    ConnectionStrings["connectionStringName"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: [MSDN, System.configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx). It needs `System.Configuration.dll`.

Answer (score 67):

**C#**

```
// Add a using directive at the top of your code file    
using System.Configuration;

// Within the code body set your variable    
string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionStringName"].ConnectionString;
```

**VB**

```
' Add an Imports statement at the top of your code file    
Imports System.Configuration

' Within the code body set your variable    
Dim cs as String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("connectionStringName").ConnectionString
```

Comment: "Add a reference at the top of your code file" => that's a using directive, not a reference!

Answer (score 27):

Add `System.Configuration` as a reference then:

```
 using System.Configuration;

 ...

 string conn = 
    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionName"].ConnectionString;
```

Answer (score 20):

I guess you need to add a reference to the *System.Configuration* assembly if that have not already been added.

Also, you may need to insert the following line at the top of your code file:

```
using System.Configuration;
```

Answer (score 17):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
```

C#

```
string constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ABCD"].ConnectionString;
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
```

BELOW WEB.CONFIG FILE CODE

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ABCD" connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-SU3NKUU\MSSQLSERVER2016;Initial Catalog=TESTKISWRMIP;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

In the above Code ABCD is the Connection Name

Comment: **Addition:** Besides the indexer that accepts the name of the connection string, it is also allowed to use integer indices - which is useful if you want to read all connection strings in a `for` loop (`for (int i = 0; i < numOfConnections; i++) { var conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[i]; ... }`) and make them selectable in a combobox. With `var numOfConnections = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.Count;` you can determine how many connection strings exist. In this example `conn.Name` contains the name of the connection.

Answer (score 15):

In `VB` : This should work

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SQLServer").ConnectionString
```

In `C#` it would be (as per comment of Ala)

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLServer"].ConnectionString
```

Comment: Those parentheses need to be brackets.

Comment: @CharlesBurns,Thanks, I wrote in VB by mistake, in C# sure it should be 
`ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLServer"].ConnectionString`

Comment: Ahh, I didn't even realize that was VB. I thought it was a typo. In a way, my mistake too.

Answer (score 11):

You have to invoke this class on the top of your page or class :

```
using System.Configuration;
```

Then you can use this Method that returns the connection string to be ready to passed to the sqlconnection object to continue your work as follows:

```
    private string ReturnConnectionString()
    {
       // Put the name the Sqlconnection from WebConfig..
        return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBWebConfigString"].ConnectionString;
    }
```

Just to make a clear clarification this is the value in the web Config:

```
  <add name="DBWebConfigString" connectionString="....." />   </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: In Web project is better to use WebConfigurationManager in System.Web.Configuration.

Answer (score 9):

```
using System.Configuration;


string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConStringName"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
using System.Configuration;


string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConStringName"].ToString();
```

Remember don't Use ConnectionStrings[index] because you might of Global machine Config and Portability

Answer (score 2):

First add this:

```
using System.Configuration;
```

Answer (score 1):

Everybody seems to be suggesting that adding

```
using System.Configuration;
```

which is true.

But might I suggest that you think about installing ReSharper's Visual Studio extension?

With it installed, instead of seeing an error that a class isn't defined, you'll see a prompt that tells you which assembly it is in, asking you if you want it to add the needed using statement.