# EF 5 code first - using a method to determine the connection

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

Is it possible that the connection string is redirected to a method (instead using App.config)?

(App.config is not an option because the location for a sdf can be changed)

My connection string (sdf) can change via an OpenFileDialog for instance.

[The hint concerning SQLExpress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556606.aspx) was seen.

When debugging, the migration goes towards the `IMigrationMetadata.Id`.

Then, `DataException - An exception occurred while initializing the database.`
      at

```
System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection)
    ProviderIncompatibleException - The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string.
    {"An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. "}
```

at `System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Utilities.DbProviderServicesExtensions.GetProviderManifestTokenChecked(DbProviderServices providerServices, DbConnection connection)`

The default ctor applies a connection string that cannot be used:

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Namespace.AbacusContext;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFrameworkMUE
```

But when invoking

```
this.Database.Initialize( false ); //good connStr applied
```

within a ctor (incl. arguments), then the default ctor is automatically invoked (but not by me) and that uses an impaired connection string. See overview:

```
 public AbacusContext( DbConnection connection, bool contextOwnsConnection ) :
            base( connection, contextOwnsConnection )
        {
            Database.SetInitializer( new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<AbacusContext, Configuration>() );
            string goodConnStr = this.Database.Connection.ConnectionString;//was used for a breakpoint
            this.Database.Initialize( false );
        }

        public AbacusContext() 
        {
           string badConnStr = this.Database.Connection.ConnectionString;
            //SQLExpress and some other stuff can be seen now
        }
```

Comment: So you are trying to change your connection string at runtime? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20216147/entity-framework-change-connection-at-runtime

Comment: have read the content. it does not fit for me. still the same issue.