# C# swap between connection strings web.config Membership provider

Tags: c#, connection-string, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

In the application we have 2 connection strings for membership provider.
We create users based on the 2 connection strings and their properties: `minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="2" minRequiredPasswordLength="8" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"` for users and `minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"` for admins. 
How we can change the active connection string when creating a user or an admin?

**Code**

```
//Code needed to swap to User connection string
MembershipUser newUser = Membership.CreateUser(username, password, email, question, answer, isAproved, out cs);
Membership.UpdateUser(newUser);
Roles.AddUserToRole(username, "User");

//Code needed to swap to Admin connection string
MembershipUser newUserAdmin = Membership.CreateUser(usernameAdmin, passwordAdmin, emailAdmin, questionAdmin, answerAdmin, isAprovedAdmin, out cs);
Membership.UpdateUser(newUserAdmin);
Roles.AddUserToRole(usernameAdmin, "Administrator");
```

Comment: [Entity Framework change connection at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20254520/3110695)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try that:

```
var p = (SqlMembershipProvider)Membership.Providers["name_of_membership_provider"];

MembershipUser newUser = p.CreateUser(username, password, email, question, answer, isAproved, null, out cs);
p.UpdateUser(newUser);
```