# Invalid character in a Base-64 string for connection string

Tags: asp.net, ado.net, enterprise-library

I have a Sql Server 2008 R2 connection string that looks like

```
  <add name="DBConnectionString"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
connectionString="Data Source=AYZ;Initial Catalog=AYZ;User ID=AYZ;Password=AYZ;"/>
```

When trying to create a new instance of SQLDatabase using EnterpriseLibrary.Data I get the above error.

```
connString =ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["DBConnectionString"];
Database objDB = new SqlDatabase(connString);
```

connString has the following

```
Data Source=AYZ;Initial Catalog=AYZ;User ID=AYZ;Password=AYZ;
```

The detailed exception is as follows :

```
System.FormatException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Invalid character in a Base-64 string.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s)
       at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database.DecryptConnectionString(String strEncyptConStr)
       at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database..ctor(String connectionString, DbProviderFactory dbProviderFactory)
       at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Sql.SqlDatabase..ctor(String connectionString)
       at ABC.GRC.DAL.CommonDAL..ctor() in D:\ABC\Projects\Right Price\ABC.GRC\ABC.GRC\ABC.GRC.DAL\CommonDAL.cs:line 31
       at ABC.GRC.BLL.CommonBLL..ctor() in D:\ABC\Projects\Right Price\Syntel.GRC\Syntel.GRC\Syntel.GRC.BLL\CommonBLL.cs:line 14
       at Global.Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\ABC\Projects\Right Price\ABC.GRC\ABC.GRC\ABC.GRC.WEB\App_Code\Global.asax.cs:line 60
       at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.HttpApplication.RaiseOnError()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: could you tell what is inside of `connString`, before creating `slqDatabase`

Comment: what you have at `CommonDAL.cs:line 31` and `CommonBLL.cs:line 14`?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is the problem

```
connString =ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"];
```

It should be

```
connString =ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["DBConnectionString"];
```

Since you have key `DBConnectionString` in you configuration file not `ConnectionString`.

Useful link:

1. [Read connection string from web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134359/read-connection-string-from-web-config)

Comment: Thanks for your response. That was a typo. Its been corrected