# ASP.NET connection string to local SQL Server database, using web.config

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, connection-string

Why is `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection` class throwing an exception that "The parameter is incorrect"?

I'm attempting to learn how to set up database connections using a local SQL database and an ASP.NET MVC project, using .NET framework 4.5.

Here are the steps I've taken that lead up to this:

1. Created a new SQL Server database in my project `App_Data` folder, called `TestSQLdb.mdf`.
2. Created a connection string in `web.config`:

   ```
   <add name="SQLTestConnection1" 
        connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB);initial catalog=TestSQLdb;Integrated Security=true" />
   ```
3. Access the connection string through

   ```
   string cn_str = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLTestConnection1"].ConnectionString;
   ```

   (See [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6134384/2658159) thread for more info on this).
4. Created a new connection:

   ```
   SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cn_str);
   ```
5. Attempt to open the connection:

   ```
   try
   {
        conn.Open();
   ```

   At this point, an exception is thrown.

I tried to set this up so it would be simple and easy to learn on. What am I missing?

Comment: Do you really call a method `cn_str()` in your `new SqlConnection` or is it just a typo?

Comment: @PilgerstorferFranz: the `cn_str()` method is correct in my code, but for example here it should just be `cn_str`. Thanks for pointing it out. I'll edit my question, since this was also pointed out by @NightOwl888 in his answer below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you are working with a localDB you'll have to specify a **AttachDbFileName** attribute in your connectionString. This attribute should point to your **TestSQLdb.mdf** file. Initial catalog is the name of your dataBase within your mdf file.

see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752(v=vs.110).aspx#localdb) for this example

```
<add name="ConnectionStringName"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\DatabaseFileName.mdf;InitialCatalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
```

Comment: Yep, that got it. +1 for the helpful link.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing a variable to the `new SqlConnection`, you are instead trying to call a function called `cn_str`.

To get it to work, you need to remove the parentheses from the name.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cn_str);
```

Comment: Umm, my fault I didn't point out that I'm actually using a function to get `cn_str`. Thanks for pointing that out, but it's not actually the problem here I think. I'll edit my question if needed.

Comment: If this had been the problem, the error message would have been different and the exception would have happened at a different time.