# C# Connection String Write-Read .ini

Tags: c#, ini

I want to write and read my connection string in the Baglanti.cs class, but I don't know anything about this. I trying this first time. I search on Google, but I can't find any clear information.

Comment: A .cs file is code file that is converted to runtime code during compilation. After successful one you end up with an application, library and so on. When your code is executed you have no such files in execution context, they are part of the whole compiled app/lib.

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134359/read-connection-string-from-web-config

Comment: why do you have .ini in the end of caption??

Comment: my boss want me do with .ini file :D

Answer (score 2):

The .NET way of doing this is using `app.config` file instead of .ini file

1. Create a new Application Configuration File with the following content

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <configuration>
       <connectionStrings>
           <add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="YourConnectionString" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
       </connectionStrings>
   </configuration>
   ```
2. Retrieve the connectionString inside your application using

   ```
   var connection = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
   ```

### Check out [MSDN: Connection Strings and Configuration Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms254494(v=vs.110).aspx)