# VB Net - How to create SQL connection string when string located in Web Config file?

Tags: vb.net

My program has a SQL connection string hard coded in place:

```
Public SQLconn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=Database444;Initial Catalog=SQL3;User ID=user;Password=user")
```

Now I realized that there is a connection string stored in the Web.config file called `connectionString` and I want to link to that instead of hardcoding it on my program.

So I tried this:

```
Dim SQLconn As String = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;" & connectionString.ConnectionString
```

Now I get the error `The name connectionString is not declared`.

I've also added in the imports settings, but still no luck

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data.Odbc
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Globalization
```

What else am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read connection string from web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134359/read-connection-string-from-web-config)

Comment: I checked the duplicate question, its correct answer is already included in my code. `system.configuration` is already included in the code.

Comment: `Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("connectionString")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found one answer after scrounging the Internet.

```
'first I need to declare this on my public class
Private connectionStr As String = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("connectionString")


'then do this
Public SQLconn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connectionStr)
```

In hindsight I kinda asked this question in a panic.