# How to get Microsoft Dynamics CRM root service address?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

I was reading the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/connect-customer-engagement-web-services-using-oauth) and stuck in a problem that I do not know how to get Dynamics `resource` for acquiring `access_token` using any API (I know my CRM root service address but I do not want to hard-code this service name in my code base). Could you please provide me with the solution to this problem?

Comment: `string resource = "https://mydomain.crm.dynamics.com"` mydomain is the name of your organization... do you want to get this info dynamically ?

Comment: Yes, exactly! But I need to fetch this info using any possible REST request.

Answer (score 0):

You need not to hard code it in code base like showed in documentation sample. But normally we will keep this in `web.config` or `app.config` xml file just like any connection string & [consume it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6134359/7920473).

[Use connection strings in XRM tooling to connect to Common Data Service for Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/xrm-tooling/use-connection-strings-xrm-tooling-connect)

Comment: Sorry that I did not mention that I`m looking for REST request to get info about my service name. Can it be also done by using any request to the endpoint? For now I`m using such an API "/api/data/v9.0", but it requires 'access_token' to do that and to acquire 'access_token' you need resource, so how can I retrieve it(resource = service name)?

Comment: @PavloMykhailyshyn I feel like you cannot circumvent that scenario.. in other words chasing the own tail..  I remember the old days of on premise CRM with multi tenants concept - we will do a discovery service call to pull all the orgs & iterate them. you are looking for something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Online Management API to get a list of all the Dynamics 365 instances in your Office 365 tenant. I believe this is what the Plugin Registration tool does when you check "Display a list of the Organization(s)".

This looks useful:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/online-management-api/sample-quick-start
>
> The C# sample demonstrates how to authenticate to the Online Management API and then retrieve all Customer Engagement instances from your Office 365 tenant.

Comment: Which token type should I use to retrieve the information from the request to GET `https://admin.services.crm4.dynamics.com/api/v1.1/instances`